# C++ Why does these codes work?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

Why is it possible to print 'e' after it was removed?

```
set <int> s;
for (auto &e : s){
    s.erase(e);
    cout << e;
}
```

Same occurs here,

```
list <int> l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
auto it = l.begin();
```

Why does this works

```
l.erase(it++);
cout << *it;
```

and this doesn't?

```
l.erase(it);
it++;
cout << *it;
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases you have undefined behaviour.  In the first `e` is a reference to an object which has been destroyed (a dangling reference).  Any access to that reference is undefined behaviour.  It can crash, print a random number, or format your hard disk.  It appears in this case to have printed the number you first thought of.

In the case of the list, the case that works is behaving like:

```
auto it2 = it;
it++;
l.erase(it2);
cout << *it;
```

In the second case you do:

```
l.erase(it);
// it is no longer valid at this point.  You cannot use it.
it++;  // Undefined behaviour.
cout << *it; // Anything can happen
```

Comment: The range-based loop also has the same bug as the final case (since range-based loops are defined in terms of a loop incrementing an iterator).

Answer (score 2):

**It *doesn't* "work".**

It only *seems to work*, by pure chance.

Your program in fact has a fatal bug.

Compilers don't detect this bug for you in the general case (because they can't) so your code still compiles. And the C++ runtime doesn't do memory bounds checking for you in the general case (because you don't *pay for what you don't use* and this would be an expensive feature forced on us) so your code still runs.

But you wrote an invalid program.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of lists when you pass the argument it++ the iterator has been increment after assignment to erase function  thus iterator it is still valid and pointing to the next element in the set.

In the second case the iterator is invalid as it has been erased before the incrementation .